# How many copies of the data does Entity Framework make when loading an entity?

Tags: .net, performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, blob

I've taken over an Entity Framework 4.1 project where a choice has been made to store large BLOB's in the database (max 200MB). These blobs are loaded in-memory via LINQ to Entities. Of course, this has a rather negative impact on performance...

It also gives me a nice opportunity to look at EF memory consumption and now I see that when I read an object containing a 50MB blob, memory increases by 150MB. I know there's a 'current values' and 'original values' collection, but what there is obviously a third copy. What is this?

Comment: Depending on how your model is created, you should be able to have just a singlr copy

Answer (score 1):

The context should by default keep a copy of both the original and current values.

For read only use you should be able to lower the memory footprint by 50M by disabling changetracking.

The third copy may be some unmanaged copy of the blob, take a procdump to know for sure though.

Comment: I've managed to get down to 50MB by reading the byte array directly from the database. No time right now to learn how to take and read procdumps...